# How to Merging two DataTables in third table using stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, stored-procedures

**Table1**

```
-----------------------------
Id      | Batch    |   Qty
-----------------------------
   1       A1         5     
   2       A2         5      
   3       A3         5    
   4       A4         5
```

**Table2**

```
-----------------------------
Id     | Batch  | Qty
------------------- ----------
1         A1        6    
2         A2        6    
3         A3        6     
5         A5       10
```

**Expected result**

```
-----------------------------
Id     | Batch  | Qty
-----------------------------    
1         A1       6 (Qty updated)    
2         A2       6 (Qty updated)    
3         A3       6 (Qty updated)    
4         A4       5 (remains as same)    
5         A5       10 (row in table 2)
```

How can I achieve this in SQL Server? If anybody knows this data table operation please share..

Comment: The text in brackets is just for us?

Comment: It could be helpful if you provide the exact sql server you are dealing with , (ms-sql, oracle etc)

Comment: @tchrikch It does say "Sql Server" in the question - e.g. MS-SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) query to update Table1 based on Table2:

```
MERGE INTO Table1 as target
USING Table2 as source
ON (target.id = source.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET target.Batch = source.Batch, 
               target.Qty = source.Qty
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
    INSERT (Id, Batch, Qty)
    VALUES (source.Id, source.Batch, source.Qty)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Insert Into Table3
Select * From
((Select * from Table1
Except
Select * from Table2) as temp
UNION
(Select * from Table2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table3
(
 select * from table1 t1 full outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id` and `batch` are always correlated, we can have:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t2.id,t1.id) as id,
    COALESCE(t2.batch,t1.batch) as batch,
    COALESCE(t2.qty,t1.qty) as qty
FROM
     Table2 t2
         full outer join
     Table1 t1
         on
             t2.id = t1.id --Or on batch, or both?
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned `DataTables` explicitely, i'll show you a in memory solution with `LINQ-To-DataSet` using [`Enumerable.Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx) and a custom `IEqualityComparer`:

```
DataTable tblMerged = Table2.AsEnumerable()
             .Union(Table1.AsEnumerable(), new RowIdComparer())
             .CopyToDataTable();
```

and here's the custom `DataRow` comparer to ensure that the ID is used as distinction:

```
class RowIdComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow r1, DataRow r2)
    {
        return r1.Field<int>("Id") == r2.Field<int>("Id");
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow row)
    {
        return row.Field<int>("Id").GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Id      Batch   Qty
1         A1    6
2         A2    6
3         A3    6
5         A5    10
4         A4    5
```